# Adjust number of posts that appear on front page

Tags: nodes

I currently only have one story that posts to the front page. How do I add more?

I know it's a really n00by question but I have google and visited many different links and they all say to go to the content administration page... but then where?

Answer (score 2):

On Drupal 7: mysite.com/admin/config/system/site-information

Set the **Number of posts on front page** option to your liking.